# Why does Kotlin (community) encourage reflection in pattern matching

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, pattern-matching

Almost every `Kotlin` Android tutorial or project intensively uses `when-is` constructions like the following

```
val response : Response = //...
when(response){
   is Success   -> useResponseData(response.data)
   is Cancelled -> handleCancellation()
   is Error     -> handleError(response.errorCode) 
}
```

As far as I understand, the usage of reflection is not justified in most cases and should be avoided. I suppose that my example is that particular case when the use of reflection is justified, provided that the `Response` is `sealed` and most likely the set of its subclasses will never change. Am I correct?

Is such construction in my example absolutely "clean", or rather the compromise for the sake of code simplicity?

Comment: I'd ask is casting or checking a class even considered reflection? It's just a basic polymorphic operation.

Comment: I found this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106363/363917 regarding your question. However, at the same time, wiki says about type introspection: "Introspection should not be confused with reflection." I think that the true "polymorphic" solution would be the use of the visitor pattern in this case.

Comment: This would be a code smell without sealed classes, but even then, it occasionally is preferable to using polymorphism to solve a problem. But with sealed classes, the arguments against using `is` are eliminated. It's simple and maintainable, which are the main two arguments against using `is` without sealed classes.

Comment: [Relevant blog post: When Polymorphism Fails.](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails)